# What do you call the := operator?

Tags: go, colon-equals

I was learning about Go and was wondering if there is a name for the `:=` operator. As in `x := 4`.

The best I can come up with is the **"spider face"**.

#### Example

[image]
<sub>(source: [buzzfed.com](https://s3-ak.buzzfed.com/static/imagebuzz/web02/2009/1/13/12/anigif_now-its-even-cu-4856-1231868931-6_preview.gif))</sub>

#### Update

The reason I ask is because I'm wondering how you would read the code out loud as in during a pair programming session. It's been brought up that the official name of the operator is the "short variable declaration operator" but this is ironically too long of a name to be used frequently.

How would you read this `x := 4`?  So far I have "ex colon equals four" or "ex spider-face four"?  Are there any better ideas?

Comment: Declare & Assign the variable x the constant value 4.

Comment: I say "colon equals".

Comment: Implicit/losely assignment operator seems like a good name for me.

Answer (score 6):

[*The Go Programming Language Specification*](http://golang.org/ref/spec) calls the declarations involving `:=` “short variable declarations.” Hence the operator would be called the “short variable declaration operator.”

Comment: Is it really an "operator"?

Comment: It's not an operator, [these](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Operators) are operators. Many go talks also call it "declare and initialize" (e.g. [this](http://go-lang.cat-v.org/talks/slides/emerging-languages-camp-2010.pdf) )

Answer (score 4):

Assign? Or 'is assigned'. Actually, I'd use 'assign' but I have to type at least 30 characters...

Answer (score 3):

What about "declare as"

```
x := 4
```

You would say either:  "declare ex as four" or "ex declared as four"

If that's written as

```
var x = 4
```

It's also correct

Comment: I like this much better than my suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

This is just off the top of my head, but I'd call it "instantiate". IMHO, assign is not a good choice as it confuses it with the Pascal assignment operator. Assign is also the verb used for the "=" in go and most other computer languages.

"decinit" might work as a short-hand and that has no other meaning that I know of.

Answer (score 0):

According to the specification at https://golang.org/ref/spec#Operators, `Operators combine operands into expressions.`, this is definitely not an `operator`. (if you are unsure what exactly is an operand or an expression, figure out it can not combine. Otherwise, always check the spec https://golang.org/ref/spec#Expressions).

The paragraph about this aspect of the language available in the specification https://golang.org/ref/spec#Short_variable_declarations does not name it.

The same paragraph available in the Effective Go does not name it either, https://golang.org/doc/effective_go#redeclaration

Searching the source, i was available to find how it is defined.

https://cs.opensource.google/go/go/+/master:src/go/token/token.go;drc=master;l=80

I came to the conclusion that it is the define token.